# Eloquent query alternative

Tags: laravel, eloquent

How can I write the following in Laravel's Eloquent?

```
SELECT *
FROM
  ( SELECT real_estate.property_id,
           real_estate.amount_offered,
           payee.summa
   FROM real_estate
   LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT property_id,
             SUM(amount) AS summa
      FROM payments
      GROUP BY property_id) payee ON payee.property_id = real_estate.property_id ) yoot
WHERE summa = 0.05 * amount_offered
```

Been on this for a while now and really can't get around it. Lemme explain the whole cause for the panic.

I have two tables, one for property and another for payments made on those properties. Now at any given time I will like to query for what properties have been paid for to a certain percentage hence the 0.05 which reps 5%. As it is the query works but I need an Eloquent alternative for it. Thanks

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? Post some code illustrating your attempt at solving this.

Comment: Tried a couple of queries ranging from DB::table(DB::raw($qry)) and a bunch of others I will be posting soon, deleted them since I wasn't getting any favorable outputs @Bogdan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Anywhere you have subqueries in your SQL you'll need to use `DB::raw` with Eloquent. In this case you have a big subquery for the `FROM` statement, so the easiest way would be to do this:

```php
DB::table(
    DB::raw('SELECT real_estate.property_id, real_estate.amount_offered, payee.summa FROM real_estate LEFT JOIN (SELECT property_id, SUM(amount) AS summa FROM payments GROUP BY property_id) payee ON payee.property_id = real_estate.property_id)')
)
->where('summa', DB::raw('0.05 * amount_offered'))->get();
```

Notice I used `DB::raw` for the `WHERE` statment value as well. That's because you are doing a multiplication using a column name, and the value would otherwise be quoted as a string.

---

If you want to go a step further and build each subquery using Eloquent, then convert it to an SQL string and injecting it using `DB::raw`, you can do this:

```php
$joinQuery = DB::table('payments')
    ->select('property_id', 'SUM(amount) AS summa')
    ->groupBy('property_id')
    ->toSql();

$tableQuery = DB::table('real_estate')
    ->select('real_estate.property_id', 'real_estate.amount_offered', 'payee.summa')
    ->leftJoin(DB::raw('(' . $joinQuery . ')'), function ($join)
    {
        $join->on('payee.property_id', '=', 'real_estate.property_id');
    })
    ->toSql();

DB::table(DB::raw('(' . $tableQuery . ')'))->where('summa', DB::raw('0.05 * amount_offered'))->get();
```

In this case, the second approach doesn't have any benefits over the first, except perhaps that it's more readable. However, building subqueries using Eloquent, does have it's benefitfs when you'd need to bind any variable values to the query (such as conditions), because the query will be correctly built and escaped by Eloquent and you would not be prone to SQL injection.